# Calculate price excluding tax doesn't give the exact price

Tags: jquery

I'd like to calculate price excluding tax in real time like this :

Price included taxe (**priceTi**) = 550

TaxRate = 10 %

Price excluding tax (**priceTe**) should be = 500

The problem is that I get **priceTe** = **499.99999999999994**

```
$(document).on('keyup', "#priceTi", function () {

    var priceTe = $('#priceTe');
    var taxRate = $('#taxRate');
    var priceTi = $('#priceTi');

    if (taxRate.val() != "") {
        value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.');
        var tax = parseFloat((taxRate.val()/100) + 1) ;

        $('#priceTe').val(parseFloat(value) / tax ) ;

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the j̶o̶y̶  pain that is floating point numbers. You'll can use `toFixed()` to solve the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using .toFixed(2) you can get the desired result.

```
$(document).on('keyup', "#priceTi", function () {

    var priceTe = $('#priceTe');
    var taxRate = $('#taxRate');
    var priceTi = $('#priceTi');

    if (taxRate.val() != "") {
        value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.');
        var tax = parseFloat((taxRate.val()/100) + 1) ;

        $('#priceTe').val(parseFloat(value) / tax ).toFixed(2) ;

        return false;
    }
});
```

You can also round the to the nearest integer by using round. 
.49 will be rounded down, .5 will be rounded up.
This function is `Math.round(int)`

Comment: I have tried with toFixed(2) but it alwyas give 499.99999999999994

Comment: Given your numbers, you should get 495.00

Comment: It works now but toFixed() should be inside val() ;) like this

$('#priceTe').val(parseFloat((value) / tax).toFixed() ) ;